# Inconsistencies when creating new date objects

Tags: javascript, date

I am creating new date objects in javascript and seeing some inconsistencies depending on whether I use the dateString parameter vs the year/month/day integer parameters.

Here's an example:

```
var dt1 = new Date(1979,3,5);
var dt2 = new Date('1979-04-05');
```

[jsFiddle with example](http://jsfiddle.net/CSkds/3/)

dt1 is assigned the value: Thu Apr 05 1979 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

dt2 is assigned the value: Wed Apr 04 1979 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

Can someone explain this behavior? The second example (dt2) happens to be the format that Chrome is returning a selected date from input[type=date] elements which is why I'm trying to figure this out.

Comment: Looks like the GMT offset to me

Comment: Could you explain why you even expect `new Date('4,5,1979')` to behave in any particular way? The string `'4,5,1979'` is not even formatted as a date (not in a format I recognize, anyway).

Comment: That's what I figured. Is this by design though? Why would an offset only be used when using the dateString parameter?

Comment: `new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);`

Comment: @NPE - Sorry, had the year/month/day example wrong. I updated it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @joshb: Could you also update the fiddle to reflect your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the form `'1979-04-05'` is interpreted as a UTC date (and then that UTC date is converted to local time when displayed). The form `new Date(1979,3,5);` is interpreted as local time. You can use `Date.UTC` to force UTC time for the 3-argument form ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)).

`Date` parsing (and timezone handling in particular) is generally not uniform across browsers, and it's better not to depend on it - use UTC whenever possible, or use a separate library like [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) or [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).