# Date returning inconsistent results (depending whether leading zero exists)

Tags: javascript, date

```
> new Date('2015-1-1')
Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
> new Date('2015-01-1')
Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
> new Date('2015-1-01')
Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

// Yet...
> new Date('2015-01-01')
Wed Dec 31 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)

// Similarly: 
> new Date('2015-1-10')
Sat Jan 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
> new Date('2015-01-10')
Fri Jan 09 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Can't figure out why this is happening (Chrome 39). Is it related to octal parsing?

Firefox only accepts `new Date('2015-01-10')`, and returns what I expect: `Date 2015-01-10T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: I don't know why it does that—it's an interesting question—but it's worth noting that the format without leading zeroes is not valid [per the ECMAScript specification](https://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in a related question; it appears Chrome parses the YYYY-MM-DD format as UTC time, then converts it the local timezone. So, `2015-01-01 00:00:00` in UTC is Dec 31 in EST.

See [Inconsistencies when creating new date objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470906/inconsistencies-when-creating-new-date-objects?rq=1):

> It looks like the form '1979-04-05' is interpreted as a UTC date (and then that UTC date is converted to local time when displayed).

Apparently, a possible cross browser solution is to replace the dashes with slashes to force using local time:

```
new Date('2015-01-10'.replace(/-/g, '/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of your problem since My chrome(39.0.2171.99) gives me Jan 01 in all case. But having said this, I would like to point out that you should probably use

```
new Date(2015,1,1)
```

This is how JS Date is supposed to be initialised.

Comment: If you change your computer's timezone to EST, I think you'll get Dec 31.

Comment: This is not valid input. `new Date(2015,1,1)` is valid and `new Date('2015-01-01')` is valid, but `new Date('2015,1,1')` [is not valid](https://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15).

Comment: Oh yea. I forgot to remove the quotes.